# Only first form working inside StackLayout in Xamarin.Forms Android

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I created a frame in XAML and inside it contains forms. As you can see below, there are 3 Picker fields that the user needs to pick from. However, only the first  works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="LoanApp2.Views.LoanApplication"
             Title="Title"
             Shell.NavBarHasShadow="False"
             >

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem IconImageSource="icon_dropdown.png"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <!--Root Grid -->
    <Grid>
        <!-- Root Grid definitions -->
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- Blue frame -->
        <Frame Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" Padding="0" BackgroundColor="#62bef0" HasShadow="False">
            <!-- Contains loan history text and desc -->
                <StackLayout Grid.Row="1">
                    <Label Text="LOAN APPLICATION" FontSize="30" VerticalOptions="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
        <!-- Contains form -->
        <StackLayout  Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Orientation="Vertical">
            <Frame BackgroundColor="White" Margin="30, 20, 30, 0" Padding="30" CornerRadius="5">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Label Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur." TextColor="#62bef0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                    <Picker Title="Select Loan Type...">
                        <Picker.Items>
                            <x:String>Lorem ipsum</x:String>
                            <x:String>dolor sit amet</x:String>
                            <x:String>consectetur</x:String>
                        </Picker.Items>
                    </Picker>

                    <Picker Title="Select Loan Class...">
                        <Picker.Items>
                            <x:String>adipiscing elit</x:String>
                            <x:String>Nam gravida mauris</x:String>
                            <x:String>a velit rhoncus</x:String>
                        </Picker.Items>
                    </Picker>
                    <Picker Title="Select Purpose...">
                        <Picker.Items>
                            <x:String>tempor porta vitae</x:String>
                            <x:String>Nullam ultrices</x:String>
                            <x:String>aliquam</x:String>
                        </Picker.Items>
                    </Picker>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

The structure above is StackLayout > Frame > StackLayout > Pickers - only the first picker works

I tried experimenting and making the 2nd StackLayout's orientation horizontal, all the picker works but that's not the look I am trying to achieve.

I tried a structure like StackLayout > Pickers - and everything works but I need to wrap the pickers in a frame for UI purposes. StackLayout > Frame > Pickers does not give the desired output.

[This is a screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaaWO.png)

Comment: There is probably issue with your grid can you post full grid?

Comment: @Adlorem I've added the full code. Thanks.

Comment: Exactly as @Adlorem mentioned its an issue in `Grid`. Set `Grid.RowSpan = 4` for `StackLayout` covering the `Picker`. Or change the `RowDefinitions`. Check if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Adlorem, the problem is Grid. Since the Grid will be split the view size based on the given row definition. You mentioned the * for 5 rows. So it's split the entire view size into 5 equal sizes. But you've placed the only two rows of the element. So it's displayed within those two-row sizes.

Either based on your requirement split the size by either Auto or specified size if known. Or else place your root grid into ScrollView,

```
<Grid>
    <!-- Root Grid definitions -->
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- Blue frame -->
    <Frame Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" Padding="0" BackgroundColor="#62bef0" HasShadow="False">
        <!-- Contains loan history text and desc -->
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="1">
            <Label Text="LOAN APPLICATION" FontSize="30" VerticalOptions="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>
    <!-- Contains form -->
    <StackLayout  Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Orientation="Vertical">
        <Frame BackgroundColor="White" Margin="30, 20, 30, 0" Padding="30" CornerRadius="5">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                <Label Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur." TextColor="#62bef0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                <Picker Title="Select Loan Type...">
                    <Picker.Items>
                        <x:String>Lorem ipsum</x:String>
                        <x:String>dolor sit amet</x:String>
                        <x:String>consectetur</x:String>
                    </Picker.Items>
                </Picker>

                <Picker Title="Select Loan Class...">
                    <Picker.Items>
                        <x:String>adipiscing elit</x:String>
                        <x:String>Nam gravida mauris</x:String>
                        <x:String>a velit rhoncus</x:String>
                    </Picker.Items>
                </Picker>
                <Picker Title="Select Purpose...">
                    <Picker.Items>
                        <x:String>tempor porta vitae</x:String>
                        <x:String>Nullam ultrices</x:String>
                        <x:String>aliquam</x:String>
                    </Picker.Items>
                </Picker>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

Now your view will be like below,

[image]

Comment: I understand now, I'm a newbie to XAML and I thought what * means is expand with content. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on @Aldorem's comment and @Ganesh's answer

The Grid's Row definition is the the root cause of the issue here. Picker is overlapped by below Grid rows.

Suggestions:

1. If you wanted to split the Grid into rows proportional heights (i.e., 1:4), then set the RowDefinition's Height as below

2)Keep your `Grid`'s RowDefinition as it is if required(I don't find any necessity as per your UI) and set `Grid.RowSpan` to 4.

```
<StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="4"/>
```

3. Set the first RowDefinition's Height to Auto and second to fill remaining.

Comment: Thank you for expounding on this further!